# ClipView in JavaFX 2.0

Tags: javafx

When i google for JavaFX and ClipView nothing comes up except results with JavaFX 1.2 and 1.3. Does this mean that ClipView from version 1.3 is stopped in 2.0? I wanted to use Clipview in my project, do you know of anyway?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ClipView](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene.layout/javafx.scene.layout.ClipView.html) does not exist in JavaFX 2+, instead you can set the [clip](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty) on the node or use a [ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html) with an appropriate [ScrollBarPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.html#NEVER) and [pannable](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#pannableProperty) setting.